# Javascript onChange affecting CSS styles

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying create a 'live' view where our clients can edit the colors of a php page that they will embed into their own page.

By entering a hex value in each of the text fields, it should instantly change the background color value set for it's relative div.

```
<!--Enter a hex color to change the background of id="box1" -->
<input name="color1" id="color1" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" onchange="DOTHIS(change background color of 'box1' to this value);"  />
<br />

<!--Enter a hex color to change the background of id="box2" -->
<input name="color2" id="color2" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" onchange="DOTHIS(change background color of 'box2' to this value);"  />
<br />

<!--Enter a hex color to change the background of id="box2" -->
<input name="color3" id="color3" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" onchange="DOTHIS(change background color of 'box3' to this value);"  />

<hr />

<div id="box1" style="background-color:#ff0000">HELLO 1</div>
<div id="box2" style="background-color:#00ff00">HELLO 2</div>
<div id="box3" style="background-color:#0000ff">HELLO 3</div>
```

This is probably simple to someone, but after a couple of days, I cannot find the right way to do it.

UPDATE:

After seeing the direction of the answers, I thought I'd better add the following..

How would this work if the id names were not related?

example:

```
id="maincolor" -> affected id="hello"
id="fontcolor" -> affected id="world"
id="buttoncolor" -> affected id="foo"
```

This is why I thought it might be better to inline javascript for each element?

There are only four colours to change, plus an option to hide various divs containing text and one checkbox to hide the title..

The system is here: https://www.overseasmortgagefinder.co.uk/affiliates/generator.php

As you can see from the left side, our users can customise how the 'sourcing system' will look on their site.

What I am trying to do is create a 'live view' window on the right instead of the static help guide.

Is this any clearer as to my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without using jquery:

- Remove `onchange` from your inputs, as `onchange` wont be fired until the user leaves (blur) the field.
- Add `onkeyup="changeBackground(this)"` for each input field

Add this javascript function to your page:

```
changeBackground = function(source) {
    if (/^[a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6}$/.test(source.value)) { // test for a valid hex color
        var boxId = source.id.replace('color', 'box');
        document.getElementById(boxId).style.backgroundColor = '#'+source.value;
    }
}
```

Here is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uubWV/2/) to test.

Comment: I think is what I need. I will look into working this into the live system tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: example:

id="maincolor" -> affected id="hello"
id="fontcolor" -> affected id="world"
id="buttoncolor" -> affected id="foo"

This is why I thought it might be better to inline javascript for each element?

There are only four colours to change, plus an option to hide various divs containing text and one checkbox to hide the title..

Comment: The system is here: https://www.overseasmortgagefinder.co.uk/affiliates/generator.php

As you can see from the left side, our users can customise how the 'sourcing system' will look on their site.

What I am trying to do is create a 'live view' window on the right instead of the static help guide.

Is this any clearer as to my goal?

Comment: I understand. I dont recommend you to inline any javascript code, it tends to make your code unmaintainable. If you really need to use unrelated id names (I dont recommend this), you could use an object to map your from->to relatioships. As in your example: `var IDMAP = { maincolor: "hello", fontcolor: "world", buttoncolor: "foo" };` then in javascript you use `var boxId = IDMAP[source.id];`. Tell me if its confusing the way I explained.

Comment: If you see here:  http://overseasmortgagefinder.co.uk/affiliates/generator2.php

The 'maincolour' is everything in blue (header bars, thin borders etc).

The 'fontcolour' is the white text in the header bars.

The 'buttoncolour' and 'buttonhovercolour' are what they are.

So, in the case of the main colour, the selection on the left affects more than one object. It looks to me like I should be using Javascript to affect a 'class' instead, but it seems that Javascript doesn't do classes, right?

Comment: In this case you could add the same class to the related objects. Then use `document.getElementsByClassName` and cycle through the array of elements returned. Once again, if you use jQuery it will be a lot easier, e.g: `$('.aclass').css('backgroundColor', $(this).val())`, this snippet will apply the css rule to all elements with class `aclass`.

Comment: I have been told to put this project on hold for now. Your last tip there makes more sense. I will study jQuery for when I have to complete this project. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's a fairly dynamic approach using jquery.

Change the format of the id's of your inputs to `color-box1`, `color-box2` and `color-box3` respectively.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(function() {
>   // assigns a onChange event to all inputs with ids that start with "color-box"
>   $("input[id^=color-box]").change(function () {    
>     // validate user's input here    
>     // if valid, grab id of changed input & remove the "color-" part    
>     var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-", 2)[1];
>     // set color of div using the id above   
>     $("div#"+id).css("background-color","#"+$(this).val());
>   }); 
> });
> </script>
> ```

If you need a pure javascript solution, just shout..

Comment: But I'm not yet well versed in Javascript and I think this is a bit too complex for what I need for this one issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('box' + this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1 )).style.backgroundColor = this.value;"
```

Also, you have two `</form>` closing tags. I'd get rid of the first one.

Comment: I think is what I need. I will look into working this into the live system tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for. Thank you, I learned something from this.

Comment: Ever think of using a JavaScript library like jQuery? Once you learn it, it'll be a really useful tool.

Comment: Yes, I think I should get into it. It seems very popular these days and would probably solve a lot of my Javascript woes.